# PG::ERROR M. Hartl's Ruby on Rails Ex. 3.5.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, railstutorial.org, rails-postgresql, pg

Noob here trying to work through M. Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.  Attempted the advanced exercise [#3.5.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-pages_controller_spec_exercise) to change the database adapter from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL.  Now I'm getting all sorts of errors.  I would like to continue this struggle with the following advice: How do I find and examine my pg-hba.conf?  The only thing I can turn up is "pg_hba.conf.sample" in usr/share/postgresql/9.1 and an ***empty file!*** called pg_hba.conf at /etc/postgresql/9.1/main that I think I created myself while thrashing about.  Any help?  Ideas?  Did I delete it?  Can it be rebuilt?

Comment: Are you on linux or osx? How did you install postgres?

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint 13.  Hmmmm how did I install postgres?  Lemme get back on that.  That was lost week.

Comment: Going back into my terminal entries, here's what I tried: 1) heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev  That generated an error. So: 2) heroku addons:docs heroku-postgresql   Then: 3) heroku addons:add pgbackups  Then: 4) sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common  Which was a mistake.  So 5) sudo apt-get install libpq-dev That looks like it has a typo in it (should be libpg-dev?) Banging away: 6) sudo apt-get install postgresql and I have been googling errors ever since!

Comment: No, `libpq-dev` is the right package name for PostgreSQL headers.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to modify anything in your pg_hba.conf to get your Rails app connecting to your locally installed PostgreSQL. You will need to configure the `host` as being `localhost` in your database.yml file, but that's about it.

Running `locate pg_hba.conf` will tell you that the file you found in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main` is indeed the correct one for your install (I have the same file on my system). This is provided by the `postgres-9.1` package.